# VBA - Create a msgbox having it only to show once when a formulated cell changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I am trying to create a msgbox which will respond if a change is made in a column.  This column has results run by formulas and the results are in text.  For example, the formula is to check two balances.  If they match, the formulated cell will show "Matched", if they don't, it will show "Not Matched" instead.  When it is changed from "Matched" to "Not Matched", I'd like a msgbox to show to remind whoever has made an improper change to the balance.  However, here is the problem, when I run my code below, the msgbox loops and shows up multiple times as a result for each change made.  How can I have it only show up once for each change made from "Matched" to "Not Matched".  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
     Dim rr As Range, r As Range
     Set rr = Range ("L6:L57").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
     For Each r in rr
          If r.Value = "Not Matched" Then
          MsgBox "Please Checked Date Entered", vbExclamation
     End If
     Next r
End Sub
```

Please Help!

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Dim rr As Range, r As Range
  Dim bNotMatched as Boolean
  Set rr = Range ("L6:L57").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
  bNotMatched = false
  For Each r in rr
      If r.Value = "Not Matched" Then
           bNotMatched = true
      End If
  Next r

  If bNotMatched  = true then
     MsgBox "Please Checked Date Entered", vbExclamation
  End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to have a copy of "Matched/Not Matched" column with static values and every time you check for "Not Matched" value in `rr`, you can compare that value with a copy. If both are "Not Matched" then go to the next `r`. If not, then change from "Matched" to "Not Matched" in copied column and display msgbox.